Two (or more) custom hooks which send rest requests (post, put, get), do something with the results and I want they work sequentially
I have a React application, in which I need:

Set the initial state
Create an object, if the initial object doesn't exists
Update the created object
Get the updated object

I want to do this with custom hooks and local state. For now I don't want to use Redux or other state-centrilized solutions
I am a bit confused, because I haven't been working with React for some time and I forget the concept a bit... I wanted to split the code from one huge piece of code inside one useEffect and use a custom a hook per one rest request plus some logic aroud this.
This is not my real code, but it's quit close to it.
This is my main component.
function MyApp() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(myInitialObject);

  // hook where I create a new object via post request
  const { newObject } = useCreateMyNewObject(myState);

  // hook where I update the created object via put request, I dont need the result
  useUpdateMyNewObject(newObject);

  // hook where I call get method
  const updatedObject = useFetch(newObject);

  return (
    <>      
       { use properties of updatedObject }
    </>
  );
}

It calls post method twice, put - ones and get - never.
We use strict mode, and I guess this is why post method is called twice, but I have no idea why get (useFetch hook) doesn't work.
This is not real code of the useFetch hook:
const useFetch = (myInitialObject) => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(myInitialObject);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!myState?.id) {
      return;
    }

    async function fetchFromServer(id) {
       const fetchedObject = await fetchObject(id);
       setMyState(fetchedObject );
    }

    fetchFromServer(myState.id)

  }, [myState]);

  return myState;
};


My question is what do I do wrong?

Can't you put these api calls in a function like: objectTransaction? Then you can control the async workflow easily.

If there's such a coupling between two API requests that the second depends on the first then I don't see any value in trying to separate them in the React component lifecycle like this. Just create one atomic unit that makes both requests, life will be much easier that way.

There's no way for useFetch to wait until the PUT has completed. What's likely happening:

POST creates object
newObject probably starts out null and becomes something as a result of POST
useUpdateMyNewObject and useFetch kick off at essentially the same time, with the initial null value, and do nothing, then maybe again with the updated value. Seems like useFetch must be short-circuiting, suggesting newObject isn't getting updated as you expect.

At the very least, I think you need to await the PUT before calling useFetch. Checking (printing to console or watching in the debugger) on the values of newObject between the various calls will likely be helpful.
